# Time scaling of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In the ODE class, my professor wrote down the following:

The ODE $$dx/dt = f(x(t))$$ for time $t$ between $0$ and $T$ is the same as the ODE $$dx/ds = T f(x(s))$$ for time $s$ between $0$ and $1$.

I am a bit confused about the description above. How to see this? Or can anyone give me more formally description?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just change the variable: $t=Ts$.Then, $dx/dt=dx/ds\cdot ds/dt=\frac{1}{T}dx/ds$. Your new independent variable $s$ takes values on $[0,1]$ when the old variable $t$ takes values on $[0,T]$.

Comment: I'm surprised that f(x(t)) doesn't become f(x(s•T)) but you're saying it just becomes dx/ds = T • f(x(s))?

Comment: @Mossa it is a matter of notation. Following the (somehow pedantic) functional notation that mathematicians favor, one should change the name of the function and introduce $\tilde x(s)=x(t)=x(Ts)$. And the resulting equation is an equation for $\tilde x$. Engineers and Physicists keep the same name $x$, be it a function of $t$ or $s$.

Comment: This was really helpful. Thanks.